# Eclipse RCP parts can not be moved after export

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-mars

I have an Eclipse RCP e4 app that works fine when I launch it within eclipse. But when I export it using the export wizard the parts can not be moved around inside the perspective using drag&drop. I still can resize perspectives but minimize/maximize buttons disappear.

Is there some parameter I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: check in if you have all the needed files in 'build.properties'

Comment: Do you have the correct AddOns in the Application.e4xmi? Are you including the necessary plug-ins in the .product file?

Comment: After reading your comments i have found this post http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/20/drag-and-drop-e4/
I followed the instructions and have added the plugin and the addon bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon
But when running I have this exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.13.0.v20150504-0621

Are there any other plugins to add? Thx

Comment: Actually my URI was wrong the addon is in org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt. Now it works. Thx.